# Cannot access both page form and iframe form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am having an issue where I am trying to instantiate an object that pulls data from both an iframe DOM and the page DOM.

If I build the page and run it on local (without the iframe since that won't work because of cross-origin restrictions), there are no issues instantiating the object and getting the local form fields array from the page DOM.

To get the iframe form, I'm using the jQuery .content() method by instantiating the object after the iframe has loaded. Once the page has loaded, I am able to get the iframe source form fields without any problems, but then I cannot get the page form fields.

How do I access both the page DOM and iframe DOM after the iframe has loaded? Here's the code (abbreviated):

```
<form id="pageForm">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="field1">Field1</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="field1" id="field1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="field2">Field2</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="field2" id="field2"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<button type="submit" id="pageSubmit">Submit</button>

<!--local iframe -- [pageFields] is populated, but [iframeFields] is not (expected because of cross-origin)-->
<iframe id="formIFrame"></iframe>

<!--server iframe -- [iframeFields] form is populated, but [pageFields] is not-->
<iframe id="formIFrame" src="<!--URL goes here-->"></iframe>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function FormManager(iframeDOM,iframeForm,pageForm){
        this.pageFields = $(pageForm).serializeArray();
        this.iframeFields = $(iframeDOM).contents().find(iframeForm).serializeArray();
    }

    //[pageFields] is populated, but [iframeFields] is not (expected because of cross-origin)
    const formManager1 = new FormManager('iframe#formIFrame','form#aspnetForm','form#pageForm');
    console.log(formManager1);
    debugger;

    //[iframeFields] form is populated, but [pageFields] is not
    document.getElementById('formIFrame').onload = function () {
        console.log('iframe is loaded');
        const formManager2 = new FormManager('iframe#formIFrame','form#aspnetForm','form#pageForm');
        console.log(formManager2);
        debugger;
    };

</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm at my wits end with this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using different domain url in second frame you can not take content from this iframe. Because of "cross-origin" issues.

Please check this link;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah, that code isn't entirely clear - when I'm hosting the page on the server, the iframe is from the same server, so it's not a cross-origin issue there--and calling it from the page works. It's getting the form data from the page that the iframe is embedded in that's problematic. I can only get one form or the other. It's weird.

Comment: I prepared an example for this code,
Please check this.

https://jsfiddle.net/naklov67/kg2vjyxe/